# Any libraries/tools for playing custom video and audio formats in Windows RT?

Tags: audio, video, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am currently working on media player for Windows Store. That's will be really nice, if users can play more video/audio formats. Unfortunately, search on google hasn't bring results. I have searched in windows store: there are a few programms, that's can play mkv/flv/flac. I tried to decompile some of this apps, but haven't found any component that can be reused in my media player (all such components have been wrote by companies themselves and I can't use this components due to copyright rules).

So, what about current situation in Windows Runtime. What the fastest way to get ability to play non-standart video- and audio-formats? Maybe there are no component/library that can be just used, but I can spend a few days to make it work? Or maybe there is a way to recode audio/video in WinRT and play recoded file?

All what I have found in Google - "yeah, it possible; no, I don't know how to do it fast". That's really too long to write all for me only

Comment: Copyright rules? It's theft actually. StackOverflow isn't a good fit for that or finding tools/libraries.

Comment: @WiredPrairie sorry, or I have bad English (and thats true), oy you are guy, that can't read simple English text. I have decompiled some software, looked in it and haven't found components that I can reuse because that's will be a theft. I am asking SO about components that's are free to use.

Comment: You might want to check out https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/

Comment: Marked question for hold/close. Not going to debate with you in comments.

Comment: have you found a way to play any of these formats?

Answer (score 1):

Following are a list of video formats that ares supported in WinRt. So according to my knowledge playing a custom video format is out of the scope.

Please check the formats below

[Video and Audio Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx)

No such library is still available in the market. It is a limited environment to work in so Having all videos to be played in winRt Might be little difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your player would need to port codecs that are not built-in to Windows to custom Windows Media Foundation transforms and package them in your app. The custom MFTs need to avoid APIs that are unavailable to Windows RT.

If you are going to port an existing codec to an MFT, you can use the WavSource and the MPEG1Source samples in the Windows Media Foundation SDK as the starting point.